# all power to one room not working outlets read hot

Tags: electrical

We've lost all power in one room. We Replaced all the outlets in the room and the breaker for the room. all breakers and outlets read hot but no electrical is working in the affected room.

Comment: You replaced the receptacles and *then* you lost power, or you replaced all the receptacles *because* you lost power?

Comment: I lost power before replacing the outlets and breakers

Comment: How do the outlets "read hot"?   With a multimeter, circuit tester, or ?    What led you to suspect that all of the outlets and/or breaker needed to be replaced?   It might give us some clues on how to help you.

Comment: Used a multimeter as far as why I replaced breaker and outlets.....because its logical

Comment: Maybe one of the outlets in that room has problem with the neutral wire connection??? I read that.

Comment: If your neutral is open upstream or at the first device then you can read power with a glow stick or DMM from hot to ground but hot to neutral will be dead and hence nothing will work.

Answer (score 1):

This is almost certainly a neutral problem. The trouble will be in the last working device or the first dead one. If everything on the circuit is out it could be a bad termination in the panel.